# Best way to refrence json block that doesn't have a unique field in order to pass it to another page?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I've got a large template file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SelfhostedPro/selfhosted_templates/master/Template/template.json) that I'm accessing in a for loop to print a table with some values in it. When a user clicks on one of those values I'd like it to carry over just that 1 json block to another page in order to have it prefill some fields. I'm having trouble getting my program to select that single entry in the json dict in order to render the next page. Here's the code involved:

views.py

```
@apps.route('/add')
@login_required
@admin_required
def view_apps():
    """ View available apps """
    template = Template.query.all()
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    json_content = combine_json_templates()
    print(json_content)
    print(len(json_content))
    return render_template('apps/add_app.html', apps=json_content)

def combine_json_templates():

    master_list = []

    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(cwd)
    json_storage = 'app/storage/templates/json/'


    for file in os.listdir(json_storage):
        with open(json_storage + file) as json_path:
            json_content = json.load(json_path)
            for item in json_content:
                master_list.append(item)


    return master_list

@apps.route('/add/<int:app_id>')
@apps.route('/add/<int:app_id>/info')
def app_info(app_id):
    app = json_content[""+app_id+""]
    print(app)
```

add_app.html (code that displays the table and contains the onclick:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
                <table class="ui searchable sortable unstackable selectable celled table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for('apps.app_info', app_id=apps.pop(['name'])) }}';">
                            <th class="sorted ascending">Title</th>
                            <th>Desctiption</th>
                            <th>Catagory</th>
                            <th>Platform</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for a in apps | sort(attribute='title') %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ a.title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.categories }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.platform }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

The part that I'm having trouble with is getting a unique value in order to pass it onto the next page and reference the correct json.

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for('apps.app_info', app_id=apps.pop(['name'])) }}';">
```

Should I be using a different method for referencing the json file? Should I be modifying it when loading the json files in order to add some kind of key?

This is my first flask project so I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

Comment: What do you mean by the index within 'apps'?

Comment: That's definitely understandable. I'm still new to flask so it's a bit confusing. Is there a better way for me to get in touch with you and explain it in a more in depth way?

Comment: Essentially in the onclick function apps is a list that contains directories (each directory has the content of one of the json blocks in the template linked above) I don't believe it's still sorting at this point. The view is a table where information from each json block is presented (using the for loop) and when clicked I'm trying to pass some kind of identifier to reference the selected dictionary (json block and it's contents) in the next page.

Comment: Is there a way for us to move this to a chat?

Comment: I have no idea about a chat, but think about my answer. Is it that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an approach, the question is whether you like it.

```
# ./__init__.py 
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__,
        # default: ./var/app-instance/
        instance_relative_config=True,
    )
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=b'change-me\n',
    )
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # init endpoints/blueprints here
    from .apps import create_module as apps_create_module
    apps_create_module(app)

    return app
```

```
# ./app/apps/view.py 

# TODO: move this to the apps configuration file
JSON_TEMPLATES_DIR = 'storage/templates/json'

def load_json_data(path):
    data = []
    for fname in glob(os.path.join(path, '*.json')):
        with open(fname) as fp:
            dataset = json.load(fp)
            data.extend(dataset)
    return data

@apps.route('/add')
@login_required
@admin_required
def list_apps():
    '''View available apps'''
    apps = load_json_data(
        os.path.join(current_app.instance_path,
        JSON_TEMPLATES_DIR))
    return render_template('apps/add_app.html', **locals())

@apps.route('/add/info', methods=['POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def app_info():
    '''View selected app'''
    ident = request.form.get('ident', None)
    if ident:
        try:
            app = json.loads(ident)
            print(app)
        except: pass
    return render_template('apps/app_info.html', **locals())
```

```
<!-- "./app/templates/apps/add_app.html" -->
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    <table class="ui searchable sortable unstackable selectable celled table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sorted ascending">Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Catagory</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for a in apps | sort(attribute='title') %}
            <tr id="app-entry-{{loop.index}}">
                <td>
                    <div class="namecell">
                        <span class="nametext" style="display: block;">{{ a.title }}</span>
                        <span class="btn-group" role="group" style="margin-top: 1rem">
                            <form method="post" action="{{url_for('apps.app_info')}}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ident" value='{{app | tojson | safe}}' />
                                <button type="submit">Setup</button>
                            </form>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{ a.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ a.categories }}</td>
                <td>{{ a.platform }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This returns   File "/home/user/dev/selfhosted/SelfhostinGUI/app/apps/views.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    return list(sorted(master_list, key=lambda k: k['name']))
KeyError: 'name'

Comment: Because the key 'Name' is not available in all entries. I will revise my version.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I would chat with you to help if I could. I'm unsure why this platform doesn't support it.

I don't know if it helps that when trying extend instead of append it fills it up with only the first keys(name, network, title, etc) but with no values associated with them.

Comment: No problem I like to help. Does it make more sense to store the json data in a global variable or don't you want to? Is the data in your application saved again in a modified form?

Comment: I would prefer not to. It's generated Everytime the page loads (due to the fact a user could have added a template) I do store individual values for what templates the user has added in order to have them easily updatable though. The data from that will prefill a form on the next page with all of the values from the template so a user can modify them before deploying.

Comment: One of my main issues was that the href that's generated should be in the for loop that shows each of the app names. Now that I'm doing that I'm able to pass through the app name (temporary) so I'll just need to find a way to have each dictionary item to have an id (integer) in order to reference it uniquely.

Comment: That is what I am pursuing in my second approach. I'm just not sure if the data contains a unique value. Are you familiar with [UUID](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) ?

Comment: The data cannot be reliably determined as unique. I think it would be best to plan for it not to be.

Comment: I am getting `NameError: name 'json_content' is not defined` Is there a way to pass that json_content back through to this new route?

Comment: There is too much data for an urlen-encoded parameter. The session cookie is not really suitable, but it is better. So far I have suppressed that. Does reloading possibly change the data record? What do you think about storing the data in a database and not in a JSON file?

Comment: I would prefer to keep it in a JSON file since it's going to be changing frequently. Is there not a way to pass this data back into a view from jinja without it going into the url? What is your github? I'll invite you to the project so you can see more of the picture. I'm sure you'll know better than me about it.

Comment: I just sent you an invite. I know you don't like making accounts but if you have discord here's a link to my server: https://discord.gg/7FYRaY